# Creating dynamic controls

Tags: android

I am trying to create a screen with some dynamic controls, well radio buttons to be precise purely for learning purposes.

I have managed to add the radio button by referencing the radio group in the main.xml file.

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.Id.types);
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
rb.setText("some text!");
rg.addView(rb);
```

What I cannot figure out is how do I set the id of the radio button?

If  use rb.setId() it wants an integer?  I am trying to basicaly do the xml bit dynamically:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rb.[setId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29)(int) is how you would set the ID.  You say "it wants an integer?" as if you find that strange.  [All View IDs are integers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) so what else would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

well if you set it in the xml file as

The yadda appears in the R.java file as an autogenerated number.  Therefore I was not sure that it was correct to assign any old number seeing as you pass text in the xml.

Comment: That text in the XML just refers to the int value in R.java